# How to serialize jQuery request with $.when done

Tags: jquery, callback

I've coded this in jQuery. 
However the callbacks are not called in the order I want (the callback in the done branch is called prior to the ones in the when branch). 
If I define `internalOrderRequest` and `rejectionReasonRequest` as simple variables (instea od functions) all works fine.
Could anybody advise?

```
                        var self = this;
                    debugger;
                    var internalOrderRequest = function() {
                        $
                                .ajax({
                                    type : "GET",
                                    url : internalOrderServiceURL,
                                    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType : "json",
                                    success : self.retrieveInternalOrderSuccess,
                                    error : self.retrieveInternalOrderError
                                })
                    };

                    var rejectionReasonRequest = function() {


                        $
                                .ajax({
                                    type : "GET",
                                    url : rejectionReasonServiceURL,
                                    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType : "json",
                                    success : self.retrieveRejectionReasonSuccess,
                                    error : self.retrieveRejectionReasonError
                                })
                    }



                        $
                                .when(internalOrderRequest(),
                                        rejectionReasonRequest())
                                .done(
                                        function(result1, result2) {
                                            $
                                                    .ajax({
                                                        type : "GET",
                                                        url : salesOrderInfoServiceURL,
                                                        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                                        dataType : "json",
                                                        success : function(
                                                                oResult) {
                                                            self
                                                                    .retrieveServiceItemSuccess(oResult);
                                                        },
                                                        error : function(
                                                                oResult) {
                                                            self
                                                                    .retrieveServiceItemError(oResult);
                                                        },
                                                    })
                                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to *jQuery.when()* documentation, when() is expecting deferred objects but you don't return any in your internalOrderRequest() and rejectionReasonRequest() methods. From *jQuery.ajax()* documentation :

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see Deferred object for more information).

Just return your ajax requests in your methods and this should work.